# How to install nic driver from file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, drivers, network-interface

I recently got an external USB network adapter and I need to install its drivers.  I found the download for the correct drivers [here](http://www.alfa.com.tw/download_show.php?combo_0=&combo_1=&combo_2=&keyword=AWUS036H&verify=3416NU&x=48&y=14).  I downloaded them and now I have the extracted zip file.  From reading other posts, I decided to read through the Readme file for installation instructions.  I found some, but with my low Linux experience, I still do not understand how to install them.  I am using Linux Mint.  Here is a part of the Readme:

```
Release Date: 2008-12-05, ver 1037 
RTL8187L Linux driver version 1037 

   --This driver supports RealTek RTL8187L Wireless LAN NIC for 
     2.6 kernel: 
     Fedora Core 2/3/4/5/6/7, Debian 3.1, Mandrake 10.2/Mandriva 2006,  
     SUSE 9.3/10.1/10.2, Gentoo 3.1, etc, Ubuntu8.04/8.10. 
     2.4 kernel: 
     Redhat 9.2, etc 
   - Support Client mode for either infrastructure or adhoc mode 
   - Support WEP, WPAPSK and WPA2PSK connection 

======================================================================================
                                Component
======================================================================================
The driver is composed of several parts:
        1. Module source code
           ieee80211
           rtl8187

        2. Script ot build the modules
           Makefile

        3. Script to load/unload modules
           wlan0up
           wlan0down

        4. Script and configuration for DHCP
           wlan0dhcp
           ifcfg-wlan0

    5. Supplicant source code: 
       wpa_supplicant-0.5.5.tar.gz 

    6. Example of supplicant configuration file: 
       wpa1.conf 

======================================================================================
                                Installation
======================================================================================
<<Method 1>>
Runing the scripts can finish all operations of building up modules
from the source code, installing driver to the kernel and starting up the nic.
        1. Build up the drivers from the source code
           make

        2. Install the driver to the kernel
           make install
           reboot

        3. bring up wlan if nic is not brought up by GUI, such as NetworkManager
           ifconfig wlan0 up
           Note: use ifconfig to check whether wlan0 is brought up and use iwconfig to 
           check your wlan interface name,since it may change wlan0 to wlan1,etc.

<<Method 2>>
Or only load the driver module to kernel and start up nic.
        1. Build up the drivers from the source code
           make

        2. Load driver module to kernel and start up nic.
           ./wlan0up

           Note: when "insmod: error inserting 'xxxx.ko': -1 File exists" comes out
                 after run ./wlan0up, please run ./wlan0down first, then it should
                 be ok..
           Note: If you see the message of "unkown symbol" during ./wlan0up, it
                 is suggested to build driver by <<Method 1>>.
```

And here are the files that I have extracted:

[image: Files with driver download]

Answer (score 1):

Most drivers have been integrated in the distribution kernels. Are you sure this isn't handled by your kernel already? A 7 year old driver is *extremely* unlikely to work with any recent kernel (say less than 5 years old).

Comment: When I plug in the network adapter, it constantly connects and disconnects. When I plugged it in on Windows, it did the same until I installed the driver from online which solved the issue. Hence causing me to think that this is a driver issue. I wouldve assumed that mint would have the drivers already too unless this could be caused by something else